# Make diagrams in Latex of Game theory

Tags: diagrams

[image: Diagram]

Hey, I'm new to Stack Exchange and Latex. Can anyone help me with how to make this diagram in Latex? 
Can anyone help me with the code?
Thank you

Comment: Welcome! There is the `istgame` package specifically for game trees. In general, trees can be created conveniently with the `forest` package.

Comment: Can you give some link or anything?

Comment: https://ctan.org/pkg/istgame?lang=en and https://ctan.org/pkg/forest?lang=en .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For game trees there is a specific package: [istgame](https://ctan.org/pkg/istgame?lang=en). The tag for this package was created only recently, so there are as of now not too many [posts tagged `istgame`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/istgame), but this may change. `forest` is generally a nice package for producing trees, and there are quite a few [posts tagged `forest`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/forest). For your tree this package is certainly a possible choice.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[edges]{forest}
\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
el/.style={edge label={node[auto,pos=0.6]{$#1$}}},
el'/.style={edge label={node[auto,pos=0.6,swap]{$#1$}}},
for tree={math content,s sep+=4em,l sep+=1.5em,edge={semithick,-latex}}
[a
 [{(2,2)},el'=f]
 [b,el=g
  [{(0,0)},el'=n]
  [{(1,3)},el=y]
 ]
]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

[image]

However, it could very well be that `istgame` is closer to what you need on the long run. Needless to say that there are many more ways of producing trees, there is a `tikz` library called `trees`, the Graph Drawing Library `trees`, the `tikz-qtree` package and so on, i.e. this list is certainly not complete.

Comment: Thank you so much! It'll be of great help. It's really good to know new things in Latex.

Comment: Hey one more question, how to create arrows the above side of a node?

Comment: @HENAM I am sorry, I do not understand "how to create arrows the above side of a node". Do you mean the grow direction of the tree?

Comment: Yes, so let's say, I need four arrows (2 on the lower side of a node and two on the upper side), and then, how to create a different node from any of those in those 4 arrows mentioned above?

Answer (score 3):

Here is an example of using the [istgame](https://ctan.org/pkg/istgame) package:

[image]

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{istgame}

\begin{document}

\begin{istgame}
\tikzset{oval node/.style={ellipse node,draw=none}}
\xtShowArrows[oval node]
\xtdistance{15mm}{30mm}
\istrooto(0){a}
  \istb{f}[al]{(2,2)}
  \istb[->-=.92]{g}[ar]
  \endist
\istrooto(1)(0-2){b}
  \istb{n}[al]{(0,0)}
  \istb{y}[ar]{(3,1)}
  \endist
\end{istgame}

\end{document}
```